# Select multiple files in long path (filename completion in brace expansion?)

Tags: linux, bash

Sometimes I want to run a command, as arguments to this command I want to supply multiple files that are located in a folder deep in the file system hierarchy, eg:

```
command /this/is/a/long/path/foobar /this/is/a/long/path/quux
```

I was hoping I could use brace expansion, and sure, this works:

```
command /this/is/a/long/path/{foobar,quux}
```

However, the filenames can be long and I would like to use filename completion (TAB-key) but it doesn't seem to work inside braces, any ideas?

Comment: I don't suppose it's possible to cd to \this\is\a\long\path and run it from there? Then the command is only command foobar\file.exe quuz\file2.exe.

Comment: This kind of completion could be appended in your `$BASH_COMPLETION`. But I do not know if this is what you want...

Comment: @olibre - could you give an example?  I would love to have this as well.

Comment: @nerdwaller My `BASH_COMPLETION` knowledge is rusty :( Moreover I have to go home in few minutes... I hope someone will answer this question using `BASH_COMPLETION` (I am also interested ;) Cheers.

Comment: @olibre No worries, I will do my homework, just knowing where to start (i.e. having a name) is a huge help.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A little workaround: in Bash, `[Ctrl]+u` deletes from the beginning of the commandline until the cursor, and puts it in memory, `[Ctrl]+y` "yanks" (paste) it back.

So assuming you want to run the command `ls` and give it as arguments files from the `./deep/below/directory/` , you  could:

1) start by entering the long dir name, preceded by a space (this will saves a few keystrokes later):
 `./deep/below/directory/` (you can use `[Tab]` as needed), followed by `[Ctrl]+u`, which will delete it and keep it in memory   (note: you do have to use './' at the beginning of the directory name if it's a relative path, otherwise bash won't autocomplete the directory names at the beginning of the commandline)

2) then type the command (and its options) followed by a space : ex:  `ls -alFtr`

3) use `[Ctrl]+y` to yank the long dir name here, and then type the beginning of the filename you seek, and use `[tab]` as you usually do to autocomplete its name (the cut directory name is still in memory, ready to be reused)

4) repeat step 3) as many times as necessary

5) `[Enter]`

Long to type, but much faster to use ^^, try it!

Comment: Of course it also works with absolute paths ^^ (I say that as a friend asked me why I insisted on the "./" : it's only so that bash can autocomplete while typing the directory name)